# Does Unisex gender need to include in form?

Tags: forms

We can't deny that in this world, the human can be classified as male, female or unisex.

I design a form for registration. Does it really  make senses to put all gender or just male or female only?

Let say, my form:

Choose your gender:
1-Male       |       2-Female       |        3-Unisex

**Note:** Does people really admit that the person was unisex?(Or become shame and preferred not to choose it?)

Comment: "unisex" is a type of clothing, not a gender identity. As for the UX part of this question, I'd first ask why you need gender information in the first place.

Comment: I need to use gender for my next process.

Comment: what is the next process? Understanding that may help in understanding what to do with this particular field.

Comment: The process will be use later on other process. The next process just save in database. I will use it to classify how many users based on gender...easy to manage the message, type of image  needed to show..etc...

Comment: Well, things like messaging can be made gender-neutral as can be the type of image needed to be shown. Granted, on something like a dating site, gender identity is going to be pretty critical, but on something like StackOverflow, it's pretty much irrelevant. So context is going to be important.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, despite cosmetic similarity. The other question (which I answered) is about people who identify as male or female, but where that **data is missing** for whatever reason. This is about people who **don't identify as male or female**. [The UK government have published guidelines on best practice](https://www.gov.uk/service-manual/user-centred-design/resources/patterns/gender-and-sex.html#section-4) - tldr; don't ask unless it's necessary, label it "gender" not "sex" unless it's medical, and **allow "unspecified"**, which is less presumptive than "other" or "no answer".